# How to bypass data URL in android "am" using IntelijIdea run/debug configuration

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I`m wondering how can I bypass android application manager shell command options, aka -d  from Intelij run/debug configuration? So I will be able to start Activity which requires URL as data in Intent.

Something similar to:
`adb shell am start -d file:////storage/sdcard0/fileToOpen.txt  -n some.package/some.Activity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I found that I can cheat during selecting an Activity and put:

```
some.package.Activity" -d "file:////storage/fileToOpen.txt
```

Key trick here is quotes just ignore error message, save configuration and run application. Trick is that  InteliJ Idea will use string without any verification and will create following shell command:

```
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -n "some.package.Activity" -d "file:////storage/fileToOpen.txt"
```

I`m using idea - community 12.0.3